# Adding a Dropdown listbox - Issue beginner

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have asked this question several times in this and various other forums, but still unable to implement it in my code.

I am [doing this example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf) , and i need to add a listbox (like in the column `MANUFACTURE`).
i am unable to display the Listbox or populate it with values from my Java class.

My java code looks like this;

```
private List<Hotel> listHotel; 


public List<Hotel> ListAllHotels() {
    return dml.displayAllHotels(); //dml.displayAllHotels() returns a List<Hotel> 
}
```

Normally i create a listbox and populate it with values using the following JFS code;

```
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{HotelDataForm.stationedHotel}" id="globalFilter" onchange="carsTable.filter()"   >
                <f:selectItems value="#{HotelDataForm.ListAllHotels}"  var="user" itemValue="#{user[1]}" itemDisabled="false" itemLabel="#{user[1]}" />
         <h:outputText value="#{carsTable[1]}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

And this works, but i am unable to add this code to the `Manufacturer` column in the link i posted. In the example they make use of `SelectItem[]` object to populate the listbox. I am clueless as in how to add and populate values to the `manufacturer` column in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the example on Page 131 of the [PrimeFaces 2.2 Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html)

> If you’d like to use a
>   dropdown instead of an inputtext to only allow predefined filter values use filterOptions attribute
>   and a collection/array of selectitems as value. In addition, filterMatchMode defines the built-in
>   matcher which is startsWith by default. Following is an advanced filtering datatable with these
>   options demonstrated.

```
<p:column
        filterBy="#{car.manufacturer}" 
        headerText="Manufacturer"
        filterOptions="#{carBean.manufacturerOptions}" 
        filterMatchMode="exact">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />
</p:column>
```

So in this example, the `carBean` should have a method `getManufacturerOptions()` that returns either `SelectItem[]` or `List<SelectItem>` containing all the values that should be in the filter dropdown list.

REFERENCE: [Javadoc for SelectItem](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html)

Comment: I have a `List<Hotel>` how do i convert it to `List <SelectItem>`

Comment: I've seen other questions that you posted on Stack Overflow and it seems like you're not willing to put in the effort to figure the basics out yourself. `SelectItem`, for example, is a very basic JSF class and there are many many examples of how to use it if you just Google it or read any book on JSF programming.